# How to create timer for quiz in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to python. I'm still a student. I got project of making a quiz program with timer. When a question is displayed that timer should start and when player give right answer, next question should be displayed and timer should also reset. And when user give wrong answer the time should stop.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a homework or code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do this

```
import time, threading
def run():
    time.sleep(5)
    next_question()
thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
thread.start()
```

Comment: But will this reset with next question or stop when wrong question is given?

Comment: You have to do it in the rest of the program. You just have to know that if you want to stop the thread you can use `thread.stop()`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) You helped me a lot.